# Prove a connection from Divergence-less (or "solenoidal") Fields Theorem from textbook by Griffiths

Tags: vectors, classical-electrodynamics, vector-fields

The following is the excerpt from 'Introduction to Electrodynamics' textbook by David J. Griffiths(p. 54):

---

### Theorem 2

*Divergence-less (or "solenoidal") fields*. The following conditions are equivalent:

(a) $\nabla\cdot$**F** = 0 everywhere.

(b) $\int$**F** ·**da** is independent of surface, for any given boundary line.

(c).....

(d) .....

How to derive (a) from (b)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer myself. If we are given a boundary line, then we can integrate say vector potential **A** over it, which equals to the integral of  derivative of the latter, according to Stokes' theorem:

$\oint\limits_{\mathscr{P}}$ **A** $\cdot$ *d***l**= $\int\limits_{\mathscr{S}}$ ($\nabla$$\times$ **A**) $\cdot$ *d***a**

Hence, comparing the integral from (b),to the r.h.s. of Stokes' theorem we come to the conclusion  that,

**F**=$\nabla$$\times$ **A**.

But, as it known from vector analysis, the divergence of a curl always equals zero. Thus, we derived condition (a)  from (b).